# Which is the best way to change a "Load More" button in a Wordpress theme?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to change a button in a Wordpress theme.
When the button is clicked, it shows more posts from a list and it changes the text inside to "Loading", as you can see below.

Which is the best way to change it with a custom picture? Is there a way to provide also the picture of the "loading phase"?

Thanks in advance

SCREENS:

**With DevTools**:

[image: screen1]

**Mousehover**:

[image: screen2]

**Clicked**:

[image: screen3]

Comment: You want to change style ??

Comment: [This](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html) might help you.

Comment: I'd like to change the button with a custom png

Comment: can you show me an example what type of custom png ?

Comment: For example like this one: https://www.stickpng.com/img/icons-logos-emojis/click-here-buttons/click-here-green-button
And providing also another png when the button is clicked and the content is loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the solution for loading.... post using with ajax. You follow the steps of info from the link [Load More Posts with AJAX](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html)

**Step 1. Load more button** - Put the code in examplefile.php file,

```html
<?php
global $wp_query; // you can remove this line if everything works for you
 
// don't display the button if there are not enough posts
if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 )
 echo '<div class="misha_loadmore">More posts</div>'; // you can use <a> as well
?>
```

```html
<style>
.misha_loadmore{
 background-color: #ddd;
 border-radius: 2px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-size: 0.875rem;
 font-weight: 800;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 cursor:pointer;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 10px 0;
 transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.3s ease-in-out;  
}
.misha_loadmore:hover{
 background-color: #767676;
 color: #fff;
}
</style>
```

**Step 2. Enqueue jQuery and myloadmore.js.** - Pass query parameters to the script.

Put the code in functions.php file

```html
function misha_my_load_more_scripts() {
 
 global $wp_query; 
 
 // In most cases it is already included on the page and this line can be removed
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 
 // register our main script but do not enqueue it yet
 wp_register_script( 'my_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/myloadmore.js', array('jquery') );
 
 // now the most interesting part
 // we have to pass parameters to myloadmore.js script but we can get the parameters values only in PHP
 // you can define variables directly in your HTML but I decided that the most proper way is wp_localize_script()
 wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_params', array(
  'ajaxurl' => site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // WordPress AJAX
  'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ), // everything about your loop is here
  'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
  'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
 ) );
 
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my_loadmore' );
}
 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'misha_my_load_more_scripts' );
```

**Step 3. In myloadmore.js file, put the script**

```html
jQuery(function($){ // use jQuery code inside this to avoid "$ is not defined" error
 $('.misha_loadmore').click(function(){
 
  var button = $(this),
      data = {
   'action': 'loadmore',
   'query': misha_loadmore_params.posts, // that's how we get params from wp_localize_script() function
   'page' : misha_loadmore_params.current_page
  };
 
  $.ajax({ // you can also use $.post here
   url : misha_loadmore_params.ajaxurl, // AJAX handler
   data : data,
   type : 'POST',
   beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
    button.text('Loading...'); // change the button text, you can also add a preloader image
   },
   success : function( data ){
    if( data ) { 
     button.text( 'More posts' ).prev().before(data); // insert new posts
     misha_loadmore_params.current_page++;
 
     if ( misha_loadmore_params.current_page == misha_loadmore_params.max_page ) 
      button.remove(); // if last page, remove the button
 
     // you can also fire the "post-load" event here if you use a plugin that requires it
     // $( document.body ).trigger( 'post-load' );
    } else {
     button.remove(); // if no data, remove the button as well
    }
   }
  });
 });
});
```

**Step 4. wp_ajax_#** - This is the AJAX handler function. Insert it to your functions.php file.

```html
function misha_loadmore_ajax_handler(){
 
 // prepare our arguments for the query
 $args = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );
 $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // we need next page to be loaded
 $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
 
 // it is always better to use WP_Query but not here
 query_posts( $args );
 
 if( have_posts() ) :
 
  // run the loop
  while( have_posts() ): the_post();
 
   // look into your theme code how the posts are inserted, but you can use your own HTML of course
   // do you remember? - my example is adapted for Twenty Seventeen theme
   get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );
   // for the test purposes comment the line above and uncomment the below one
   // the_title();
 
 
  endwhile;
 
 endif;
 die; // here we exit the script and even no wp_reset_query() required!
}
 
 
 
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_{action}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}
```

**Get the more info for follow the link, [Load More Posts with AJAX](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html)**

Thanks !!